# Rewriting an IComparer to use a lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, icomparable

I'm trying to rewrite my `IComparer<Animal>` to use a lambda expression, but I can't seem to get this done correctly

```
public class AnimalCarriageSorter : IComparer<Animal>
{
    public int Compare(Animal animal, Animal targetAnimal)
    {
        //Compare diet first.
        if (animal.FoodDiet.CompareTo(targetAnimal.FoodDiet) != 0) 
        {
            return animal.FoodDiet.CompareTo(targetAnimal.FoodDiet);
        }

        //Compare size.
        return targetAnimal.Size.CompareTo(animal.Size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how you want your comparer to work exactly.

Comment: Where is the lambda expression?  What can't you get done correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily rewrite it using `Func<Animal, Animal, int>` instead of the `IComparer<Animal>`, e.g.

```
Func<Animal, Animal, int> comparer = (x, y) => 
    x.FoodDiet.CompareTo(y.FoodDiet) != 0 ? 
        x.FoodDiet.CompareTo(y.FoodDiet) : 
        x.Size.CompareTo(y.Size)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've switched the comparison from `animal.CompareTo(targetAnimal)` to `targetAnimal.CompareTo(animal)`, so you will not get consistent results. You should have `animal` as the first object in both cases.

For example:

```
public int Compare(Animal animal, Animal targetAnimal)
{
    // Compare diet first.
    if (animal.FoodDiet.CompareTo(targetAnimal.FoodDiet) != 0)
    {
        return animal.FoodDiet.CompareTo(targetAnimal.FoodDiet);
    }

    // Compare size.
    return animal.Size.CompareTo(targetAnimal.Size);
}
```

Or you can simplify it a little:

```
public int Compare(Animal animal, Animal targetAnimal)
{
    return animal.FoodDiet.CompareTo(targetAnimal.FoodDiet) != 0 
        ? animal.FoodDiet.CompareTo(targetAnimal.FoodDiet) 
        : animal.Size.CompareTo(targetAnimal.Size);
}
```